# Make constraints for subviews programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I need to create a UISlider and put it above an existing slider.

I do know how to create constraints for a view if I want to attach it to its superview:

```
UIView *superview = view.superview;
[view setValue: [NSNumber numberWithBool: FALSE] forKey: @"translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints"];

NSLayoutConstraint *topConstraint =[NSLayoutConstraint
                                    constraintWithItem: view
                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                    relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                    toItem: superview
                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                    multiplier:1.0
                                    constant:0.0];
NSLayoutConstraint *bottomConstraint =[NSLayoutConstraint
                                       constraintWithItem: view
                                       attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                       relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                       toItem: superview
                                       attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                       multiplier:1.0
                                       constant:0.0];
NSLayoutConstraint *leadingConstraint =[NSLayoutConstraint
                                        constraintWithItem: view
                                        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                        relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                        toItem: superview
                                        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                        multiplier:1.0
                                        constant:0.0];
NSLayoutConstraint *trailingConstraint =[NSLayoutConstraint
                                         constraintWithItem: view
                                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                         relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                         toItem: superview
                                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                         multiplier:1.0
                                         constant:0.0];
NSArray *constraints = @[topConstraint, bottomConstraint, leadingConstraint, trailingConstraint];
[superview addConstraints: constraints];
```

But the same method does not work when I need to attach two subviews together. Say, I have view1 as subview of superview. It has been created some time ago. Now I need another one (view2) to have the same positioning inside superview.

Something like

```
UIView *superview = view1.superview;

UIView *view2 = [[UIView alloc] init];
[superview addSubview: view2];

[view2 setValue: [NSNumber numberWithBool: FALSE] forKey: @"translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints"];

NSLayoutConstraint *topConstraint =[NSLayoutConstraint
                                    constraintWithItem: view1
                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                    relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                    toItem: view2
                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                    multiplier:1.0
                                    constant:0.0];
NSLayoutConstraint *bottomConstraint =[NSLayoutConstraint
                                       constraintWithItem: view1
                                       attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                       relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                       toItem: view2
                                       attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                       multiplier:1.0
                                       constant:0.0];
NSLayoutConstraint *leadingConstraint =[NSLayoutConstraint
                                        constraintWithItem: view1
                                        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                        relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                        toItem: view2
                                        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                        multiplier:1.0
                                        constant:0.0];
NSLayoutConstraint *trailingConstraint =[NSLayoutConstraint
                                         constraintWithItem: view1
                                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                         relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                         toItem: view2
                                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                         multiplier:1.0
                                         constant:0.0];
NSArray *constraints = @[topConstraint, bottomConstraint, leadingConstraint, trailingConstraint];
[superview addConstraints: constraints];
```

breaks everything.

Comment: Just making things easy....assign the slider.frame = oldSlider.frame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you just have it backward...

You want to constrain `view2` ***to*** `view1`:

```
[NSLayoutConstraint
    constraintWithItem: view2    // <-- constrain this view
    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
    relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
    toItem: view1               //  <-- to this view
    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
    multiplier:1.0
    constant:0.0];
```